# First ascents by Edward Whymper

Tags: mountaineering, history, books, scrambling

[Edward Whymper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Whymper) is most known for his sweeping ascent of the Matterhorn 150 years ago. You can read about the competition with J.A. Carrel and the struggle to find a path to the top in the famous book [Scrambles Amongst the Alps](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/41234/41234-pdf.pdf). By the way indeed a nice book because Whymper made wood engravings for a living and therefore there are lots of beautiful pictures in the book made by Whymper himself!

[image]

Here a list of mountains I have read that Whymper was first climber:

- Chimborazo
- Cotopaxi
- Antisana
- Pichincha
- Cayambe
- Sincholagua

Are there more volcanos in Ecuador he climbed first? Did he first summit on his trips to the Canadian Rockies too?

Would love to get a complete list or even more infos/links for this great mountaineer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mt. Whymper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Whymper_%28Edward%29)  in Kootenay National Park, British Columbia, was first ascended by a party led by Edward Whymper in 1901.  He also got first ascent at the beautiful [Stanley Peak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Peak_(Ball_Range)), which is named after the same Stanley as the Stanley Cup, and located just across the highway from Mt. Whymper.

Comment: How do I know this? I live 44 km from both mountains :-)